# Difference between the two sigmas i.e noise sigma and filter sigma?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I know that the sigma value that we multiply with noise is used to increase or decrease the intensity level that is,

```
noise = randn(size(image)) * sigma;
```

Here sigma has something to do with intensity. But what is the purpose of sigma while creating a filter that is,

```
filter = fspecial('gaussian', size, sigma);
```

Why do we need to pass the sigma value here? What is the difference between this sigma and the one mentioned above?
Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

Sigma is the standard deviation. Read something about normal or gaussian distribution. Wikipedia e.g.

[image]

Both play a role in those functions you mentioned.
It is used to define the noise which follows the normal distribution. See the n in randn() ?
For the filter sigma defines the weights for an average calculation where the central pixel is the Gauss bell's peak. The further away the smaller the weight.